# Postman hangs (keeps loading) on sending a request to an express route

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, postman

I created this api that generates a connection request between two user (similar to linkedin or any other social media)

```
/**
 * sendRequest
 * * Send request to a user
 * TODO: Testing required
 * @param {string} from username of request send from
 * @param {string} to username of request send to
 */
User.sendRequest = (from, to) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userId = 0;
    const friendId = 0;

    User.findByUsername(from)
      .then((data) => {
        userId = data.id;
        console.log(data);
        User.findByUsername(to)
          .then((data) => {
            friendId = data.id;
            Connects.checkConnectionStatus(from, to)
              .then((areFriends) => {
                if (!areFriends) {
                  const connects = new Connects({ userId, friendId });
                  console.log(connects);
                  Connects.create(connects)
                    .then((data) => resolve(data))
                    .catch((err) => reject(err));
                } else {
                  const newError = new Error(
                    `Users ${from} and ${to} are already connections`
                  );
                  newError.status = 400;
                  return reject(newError);
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
                return reject(err);
              });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (err.status && err.status === 404) {
              reject(err);
            }
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.status && err.status === 404) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
  });
};
```

Here I am first checking if provided userids are valid of not.
I am using a model User that provides me facility to check if user exists with userid by findByUsername() function.

I checked each model individually, the are working. But On sending request on above route, postman keeps on loading. Please let me know solution.

Find by username model:

```
/**
 * findByUsername
 * * Finds a user by username
 * @param {string} username username whose detail needed to find
 */
User.findByUsername = (username) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const query = `
            SELECT 
                u.*, p.* 
            FROM user u INNER JOIN profile p 
            ON u.username = p.username 
            WHERE u.username = ?
        `;
    sql.query(query, username, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
        return reject(err);
      }
      if (!res.length) {
        const newError = new Error(`User with username ${username} not found`);
        newError.status = 404;
        return reject(newError);
      }
      console.log(`Found user: `, res);
      resolve(res[0]);
    });
  });
};
```

Connects constructor:

```
// constructor
const Connects = function (connect) {
  this.userId = connect.userId;
  this.friendId = connect.friendId;
  this.status = 1;
};
```

Method for creating connect:

```
/**
 * create
 * * Creates a new connection request between two users
 * @param {object} newConnect A connection object
 */
Connects.create = (newConnect) => {
  console.log(newConnect);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const query = "INSERT INTO connects SET ?";
    sql.query(query, newConnect, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
        return reject(err);
      }
      const response = { id: res.insertId, ...newConnect };
      console.log(`Created connect: `, response);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
};
```

THIS IS ROUTE:

```
// TODO: Send request
router.post(
  "/request",
  [body("from").not().isEmpty().escape(), body("to").not().isEmpty().escape()],
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Finds validation errors and return error object
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    const { from, to } = req.body;

    if (from === to) {
      const newError = new Error("Equal input is not allowed");
      newError.status = 400;
      next(newError);
    } else {
      User.sendRequest(from, to)
        .then((data) => res.json(data))
        .catch((err) => next(err));
    }
  }
);
```

POSTMAN BEHAVIOUR:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the Express route handler for your API. It seems from your Postman hang that your route handler never calls anything like

```
res.json(whatever).status(200).end()
```

after all your promises are resolved. Postman's patiently waiting for a response from your node express server, or a timeout.

Comment: I added  route also, please check.

Comment: You probably should use a debugger, or a console.log line, to ensure your `res.json()` line actually gets run in your server. I don't think it is.

Comment: Yes i am using console log. What actually happened is for first id (from), console is printing response but after that it is not going on

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE FIXED:
This is so embarrassing to say but yeah, I made that mistake.
In the sendRequest method, I defined constant variables userId and friendId, and I am modifying it like userId = data.id.
I changed constant variables to local variables using the let keyword.

CHANGED:
FROM:

```
const userId = 0;
const friendId = 0;
```

TO:

```
let userId = 0;
let friendId = 0;
```

But, I want an explanation of why I didn't get an error at the console when I tried changing constant variable? Did this things happens with Promises?